# Removing unwanted characters from a text column of a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am using this dataframe below

[image]

In this dataframe the "TITLE" and"ABSTRACT" column contains a lot of unwanted characters along with words.
I want only the letters and not any other unwanted characters in these two columns.
Please help me remove the unwanted charcters from both the columns of the dataframe.
Please use any method(functions preferable).

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO please take some time to tour the site and read [ask] as well as [mcve] images are discouraged as they are not reproducible - the idea is to make the question answering fluid as possible - so use text and take time to structure your question and you'll get answers in no time.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['TITLE'] = df.TITLE.str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '')
df['ABSTRACT'] = df.ABSTRACT.str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '')
```

Comment: Does the "^" exponent symbol mean "not" in regular expression??

Comment: Not in alphabet a-zA-Z